# split list into n chunks according \n in python

Tags: python

I have a list like:

```
prices=['deposit:2000$ \n monthly:500$','deposit:3500$ \n monthly:800$','deposit:2800$ \n monthly:670$',...]
```

I want to divide this list into deposit sub list and monthly sub list. I just need to split this according \n (new line). like:

```
deposit=[deposit:2000$,deposit:3000$,deposit:2800$,....]

monthly=[monthly:500$,monthly:800$,monthly:670$,...]
```

but I don't know how I can fix it.

Comment: Fix what? You didn't share any code...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pythonic way to split string into two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706735/pythonic-way-to-split-string-into-two-lists)

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension twice,

```
prices=['deposit:2000$ \n monthly:500$','deposit:3500$ \n monthly:800$','deposit:2800$ \n monthly:670$']

deposit = [item.split("\n")[0].strip() for item in prices]
monthly = [item.split("\n")[1].strip() for item in prices]
```

You can also do this in one step using zip,

```
deposits, monthly = zip(*[item.split("\n ") for item in prices])
```

Note that the returned deposits and monthly will be tuple. You can cast it to list if needed.

Comment: You loop twice over prices.. not optimal.

Comment: @balderman - Agree. Added a 1 loop solution

Comment: @Justin - As mentioned in the Q, it is list of string. so no way it will complain about ellipsis

Comment: @SreeramTP - It works now. Have an upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

something like the below

```
prices = ['deposit:2000$ \n monthly:500$', 'deposit:3500$ \n monthly:800$', 'deposit:2800$ \n monthly:670$']
deposit = []
monthly = []
for p in prices:
    d, m = p.split('\n')
    deposit.append(d)
    monthly.append(m)
print(f'{monthly} {deposit}')
```

output

```
[' monthly:500$', ' monthly:800$', ' monthly:670$'] ['deposit:2000$ ', 'deposit:3500$ ', 'deposit:2800$ ']
```